# Conditional ELSEIF does not work

Tags: vba, excel

Not sure how to solve this. "a" was meant to start from 1 to NumData, but I have deliberately change the start from 44200 to check the ELSEIF. For NumData = 117,350,

I would expect the 3rd ELSEIF to be activated. Instead throughout the whole run, it only step-into the first ELSEIF even though the "a" value does not meet the conditions.

What should I do?

```
For a = 44200 To NumData 'Int1
    If a > 1 Then
        If UCase(Trim(Range1(a, 3))) = UCase(Trim(Range1(a - 1, 3))) Then
            GoTo Line1 'Next count loop if next Platform name the same
        End If
    End If

        For b = 1 To NumData
            lat1 = Range1(a, 5)
            lat2 = Range1(b, 5)
            long1 = Range1(a, 6)
            long2 = Range1(b, 6)
            CompRad = Dist(lat1, lat2, long1, long2)

            If (CompRad <= Radius And CompRad >= 0) Then
                z = CLng(NumData / 8)
                If a <= CLng(NumData / 8) Then
                    For c = 1 To 6
                        Range2(d, c) = Range1(b, c)
                    Next c
                    Acc_Sum2 = Acc_Sum2 + Range2(d, 4)
                    d = d + 1
                ElseIf CLng(NumData / 8) < a <= 2 * CLng(NumData / 8) Then
                    z = 2 * CLng(NumData / 8)
                    For c = 1 To 6
                        Range3(e, c) = Range1(b, c)
                    Next c
                    Acc_Sum3 = Acc_Sum3 + Range3(e, 4)
                    e = e + 1
                ElseIf 2 * CLng(NumData / 8) < a <= 3 * CLng(NumData / 8) Then
                    For c = 1 To 6
                        Range4(f, c) = Range1(b, c)
                    Next c
                    Acc_Sum4 = Acc_Sum4 + Range4(f, 4)
                    f = f + 1
                ElseIf 3 * CLng(NumData / 8) < a <= 4 * CLng(NumData / 8) Then
                    z = 3 * CLng(NumData / 8)
                    For c = 1 To 6
                        Range5(g, c) = Range1(b, c)
                    Next c
                    Acc_Sum5 = Acc_Sum5 + Range5(g, 4)
                    g = g + 1
                ElseIf 4 * CLng(NumData / 8) < a <= 5 * CLng(NumData / 8) Then
                    For c = 1 To 6
                        Range6(h, c) = Range1(b, c)
                    Next c
                    Acc_Sum6 = Acc_Sum6 + Range6(h, 4)
                    h = h + 1
                ElseIf 5 * CLng(NumData / 8) < a <= 6 * CLng(NumData / 8) Then
                    For c = 1 To 6
                        Range7(i, c) = Range1(b, c)
                    Next c
                    Acc_Sum7 = Acc_Sum7 + Range7(i, 4)
                    i = i + 1
                ElseIf 6 * CLng(NumData / 8) < a <= 7 * CLng(NumData / 8) Then
                    For c = 1 To 6
                        Range8(j, c) = Range1(b, c)
                    Next c
                    Acc_Sum8 = Acc_Sum8 + Range8(j, 4)
                    j = j + 1
                ElseIf 7 * CLng(NumData / 8) < a <= NumData Then
                    For c = 1 To 6
                        Range9(k, c) = Range1(b, c)
                    Next c
                    Acc_Sum9 = Acc_Sum9 + Range9(k, 4)
                    k = k + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next b
```

Line1:

```
Next a
```

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions like:

```
1 < a <= 10
```

are always true. First part `(1 < a)` evaluates to `True` or `False` and then it is converted to integer (`True` = `1`, `False` = `0`). Both values are `<=10`.

You should change thes conditions to:

```
(1 < a) And (a <= 10)
```

Brackets are optional, comparison operators have higher precedence.

Answer (score 0):

user3964075 nailed the core issue.  I think making the code a little bit more readable will help to filter out other possible trouble areas.  Why do you set the value of 'z' and then not use it?

```
  z = CLng(NumData / 8)
```

Where are the variables d, e, f...; Range2, Range3, Range4...; Acc_Sum2, Acc_Sum3... assigned, and what are they doing?  Can each group be replaced by a single variable?

You may also want to create a simple Between function 
to clean up a lot of your conditional statements.

```
 Public Function Between(x As Integer, min As Integer, max As Integer) As Boolean
     Between = x <= max And x >= min
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, user3964075 & Carl for your prompt response. It's worked! Carl, the z variable was slotted in when I was trying to figure out the problem. I thought it would be too much to post the whole code. It does require a lot of cleaning up. Appreciate your tips.